# Code position of keystore and truststore in java servlet

Tags: java, xml, web-services, keystore, truststore

I'm working with an organization's payment API. The API automatically posts a soap request to our server when a customer makes payment and I response with an acknowledgement message in xml. (Check out the screenshots show a simple demonstration in SOAP UI)

[SOAP UI Test Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGSA8.png)

[SOAP UI Test Raw XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYXWR.png)

I made this code in Java to receive the soap request and send a response.

```
`public class testsoap extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,    
HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {

response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    ServletInputStream out = request.getInputStream();

    String xmlrpc = "";
    int c = 0;
    while((c = out.read()) != -1 ){ xmlrpc += (char)c; }

    int startTag = xmlrpc.indexOf("<TransID>");
    int endTag = xmlrpc.indexOf("</TransID>");

    String parameter = xmlrpc.substring(startTag,endTag).replaceAll("<TransID>","");

    String result="";
    //result +="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
    result +="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:c2b=\"http://cps.huawei.com/cpsinterface/c2bpayment\">\n";
    result +="<soapenv:Header/>\n";
    result +="<soapenv:Body>\n";
    result +="<c2b:C2BPaymentConfirmationResult>C2B Payment Transaction "+parameter+" result received.</c2b:C2BPaymentConfirmationResult>\n";
    result +="</soapenv:Body>\n";
    result +="</soapenv:Envelope>\n";

    response.getWriter().println(result);

}

}`
```

Now I need to add the location of my keystore and truststore.
Should I add this code just before I start preparing a response?

```
` System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",path_to_keystore);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword",akeystorepassword);

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",path_to_your_cacerts_file);
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword",atrustsorepassword)`
```

Or do I need to make a snippet that makes secure connection using the keystore and truststore rather than just setting a system property?

Comment: or Is this not the appropriate way of doing this whole scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Java class and write all the functionalities that you need to publish as a methods. Then you need to publish those functionalities as a WSDL to be consumed by your clients. See the following tutorial that will take you in step by step to publish a web services:

[Step by Step JAX-WS Web Services with Eclipse, TomEE, and Apache CXF](http://blog.sortedset.com/step-by-step-web-services-with-tomcat-tomee-apache-cxf-eclipse/)

[Building a Simple Web Service ? A Tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/webservices/buildingsimplewebservice.shtml)

[Implementing a simple web service](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Implementing_a_Simple_Web_Service.pdf)

Further based on your requirements you can have complex object as an input parameter like `C2BPaumentConfirmationRequest` and `KYCInfo` in your case

Comment: Salman, sorry I forgot to mention, I already have an existing WSDL file. The organization provides the API.

Comment: @BrianHawi Then in this case you are acting as a client and the payment organization acting as the server. In this case you can create a code from the WSDL link given to you using many tools like for example Axis1.x, Axis2 and Apcahce CXF. Following link show the way to do that using Eclipse [Generating a
client from WSDL](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/education/web/t320/Generating_a_client_from_WSDL.pdf)

Comment: am I still acting as client? cause the organization posts the data to my server and I save the data in a database and then reply with an appropriate response...

Comment: @BrianHawi If the organization's system posting a request to your system then your system immediately response back to them in the same session , then you can follow the answer I post where you can provide the organization your own WSDL. Keep in mind that in this case you are acting as server and the organization's system is acting as a client. On the other hand, if you need to post a request to the organization server in different session (not related to the first scenario), then you need to create a client from the WSDL given to you by organization's team. For that follow my first comment.